# ReferenceError: Equals is not defined: Selenium IDE Custom Format

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I am attempting to add custom functionality to the selenium IDE.  I add the custom functions to user-extensions.js and they work as expected in the IDE.  Where my issues arise is exporting the new function. I plan to add on the existing C#/Nunit/Webdriver format so I click add and copy paste the existing cs-wd.js file into my new format save it and restart Firefox.  Whenever I click on the new format I created I get a JavaScript error: "an error occured: ReferenceError: Equals is not defined"

```
Equals.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.e1.toString() + " == " + this.e2.toString();
};
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: and do you reference cs-wd.js anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Good question :D. I had the same problem today. I started to look at The Perl-rc code formatter extension on how they did it. There I foud this line:

```
     var subScriptLoader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
     subScriptLoader.loadSubScript('chrome://selenium-ide/content/formats/remoteControl.js', this);
```

This seems to load remoteControl.js into the global Object of your own script, making Equals and NotEquals available to your script: for more information, see [Mozilla's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader).

Update: After that you should also add the line:

```
     subScriptLoader.loadSubScript('chrome://selenium-ide/content/formats/webdriver.js', this);
```

to the script, to avoid the error of WDAPI not being defined.